# in webdriverio After selecting value from dropdown..selected value is changing to default value..how to handle it.. manually it working fine

Tags: javascript, automation, drop-down-menu, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

After selecting value from dropdown..selected value is changing to default value after refresh..how to handle it.. manually it working fine. is there any way we can handle dropdown values after selecting value selected value should not be changes to default value. using webdriverio

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.